# Button selector on API 10 not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I have the following Button style:

```
  <style name="ButtonmyTimeRed" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">64dip</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_selector_red</item>
</style>

<style name="ImageButtonmyTimeRed" parent="android:Widget.ImageButton">  
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_selector_red</item>
</style>
```

with the following selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<!--<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"   android:drawable="@drawable/button_shape_red" />-->
<!--<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"   android:drawable="@drawable/button_shape_disabled" />-->

<!--<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_shape_red" />-->

<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_shape_red_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_shape_red" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_shape_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"  />

<!--<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_shape_red" android:state_enabled="true"  />-->

<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_shape_red"/>


</selector>
```

My shape looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<solid android:color="@color/red" />

</shape>
```

Everything works fine on Api level 14 and above. I don't have custom values-xx folders, so I'm wondering why my button has no background on the API 10 device.

My base theme is:
Theme.AppCompat.Light
and I'm using:
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'

The strange thing is that my ImageButton has the correct background.

UPDATE:
Seems "solid" does not work on onlder devices. When I put:

```
<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="@color/red" />
<solid android:color="@color/red" />
```

I get a red border but no background